# SQL Server: update value of a column in one table based on the matching value of another column in the same table to another table's column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here's the dilemma that I have:

- `table1` has columns employee, `employeeID`
- `table2` has columns `uniqueEmployeeName`, `id`
- `table1` has a foreign key constraint on `employeeID` to the primary key of `table2`, `id`.
- column `employee` in `table1` can match one of the values for `uniqueEmployeeName` in `table2`
- column `employeeID` in `table1` is currently empty, and I would like to update it with `table2`'s column `id` based on matching `employee` in `table1` to `uniqueEmployeeName` in `table2`.

This is what I have so far:

```
update table1 
set table1.employeeID = (select distinct id 
                         from table2 
                         where uniqueEmployeeName = table1.employee)
```

The issue is that the query just runs endlessly, so I'm not sure where my query has gone wrong for what I want to do. Can anyone see where my logic went wrong?

Here's example of what the before and after should look like:

BEFORE:

```
table1                                   table2                                
employee      employeeID                 uniqueEmployeeName     id
bob                                      peter                  1
saget                                    pipper                 2
                                         saget                  3
                                         bob                    4
```

AFTER:

```
table1                                   table2                                
employee      employeeID                 uniqueEmployeeName     id
bob           4                          peter                  1
saget         3                          pipper                 2
                                         saget                  3
                                         bob                    4
```

Comment: How large are your tables?  Is it still running or did you kill the query?  If you have very large tables you may just need to let this query run until it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

If there are too many records in table1 you can use TOP() in update statement. Inner join should help as well.

```
declare @rows int
set @rows = 1
while @rows > 0
BEGIN
update top (1000) table1 
set employeeID = table2.id 
from table2 inner join table1 on table2.uniqueEmployeeName = table1.employee
where table1.employeeID is null
-- or table1.employeeID = ""
set @rows = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```